# How to Display/Hide Binded Field in Repeater Control eg. (if the field is null then hide)

Tags: asp.net, conditional-statements, repeater, show-hide

i have a repeater control with some binded columns to it i want to display/hide 
specific columns conditionally...

eg: if three columns in repeater control and if it is null then hide and if notnull show that field...

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0):

In this example i am using property of type string, if your property is from different type, typecast it to that type

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrRepeater" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate>
          <table>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
               <td id="column" runat="server" visible='<%#(string)Eval("PropertyName") != null ? true : false%>'>
                    <!-- Some control(s) to show data from -->
               </td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
          </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```